# Maximal subalgebras of $F(\Omega,X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, $\Omega$- is some signature. $\Omega$ - terms are all elements from $X$, $0$-arity symbols from $\Omega$, and $\forall \omega\in\Omega$ of arity $n$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in X$ - are terms, then $\omega(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is also a term. $F(\Omega,X)$ - is the set of all terms over $X$.

Task:
Prove that for every $x\in X$ the set $F(\Omega,X)\setminus \{x\}$ is a maximal subalgebra of the free algebra $F(\Omega,X)$ and that $F(\Omega,X)$ has no other maximal subalgebras.

What I tried:
Let $F(\Omega,X)\setminus \{x\}$ is not a maximal subalgebra of the algebra $F(\Omega,X)$, then Exists $A$ that is is a maximal subalgebra and $A \neq F(\Omega,X)\setminus \{x\}$ so it has to be сlosure under operations in $\Omega$. $\forall a,b\in X,\omega\in\Omega: \omega(a,b)\in A\Leftrightarrow A=F(\Omega,X)$.
So $F(\Omega,X)\setminus \{x\}$ is a maximal subalgebra of the algebra $F(\Omega,X)$. But I don't know if it's correct and what to do with "$F(\Omega,X)$ has no other maximal subalgebras"

Comment: Don't forget to explain what you have tried. "No effort" questions are not liked here.

Comment: I assume that means all maximal subalgebras are obtained by throwing out exactly one element.

Comment: You mean, F(Ω,X)∖ {x_1} is a maximal subalgebra and F(Ω,X)∖ {x_2} is another maximal subalgebra, but F(Ω,X)∖ {x_1; x_2} is not a maximal subalgebra?

Comment: But why would it be closed under operations? How can we be sure $x$ is not the result of some operation?

Comment: I think "why would it closed under operations?" follows from the task condition - "F(Ω,X)∖ {x} is a maximal subalgebra", so F(Ω,X)∖ {x} is already subalgebra - is closed under operations. And we have no way of verifying this, as for me.

Comment: No, the task is to show that $F(\Omega,X)\setminus \{x\}$ (whatever that means) is a subalgebra and also maximal (the only algebra that properly contains it is $F(\Omega,X)$).

Comment: Sure, Let X be a non-empty set, Ω- is some signature. Ω - terms are all elements from X, 0-arity symbols from Ω, and ∀ω ∈ Ω of arity n and a_1...a_n ∈ X - are terms, then ω(a1...an) is also a term. F(Ω,X) - is the set of all terms over X.

Comment: Good, edit your initial post with that information, please.

Comment: Is it possible to make sure x is not the result of operation if we don't know operation from Ω? Maybe we should consider two cases: 1) x is not the result of operation from Ω; 2) x is the result of operation from Ω ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf F$ denote the term algebra $F(\Omega,X)$.

It is clear that $\mathbf F\setminus\{x\}$ is a sub-algebra of $\mathbf F$, for each $x \in X$, and thus a maximal one (because it's a maximal proper subset).

Now, let $A$ be a proper sub-algebra of $\mathbf F$ and $t(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbf F \setminus A$.
Then, for some $1 \leq i \leq n$, we have $x_i \notin A$, whence $A \leq \mathbf F \setminus \{x_i\}$.
So $A$ is a maximal sub-algebra of $\mathbf F$ iff the only such term $t(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ takes the form $x_i$, for some $i$, and then $A$ has the form that you describe.

Comment: Could you explain why F∖{x} is a sub-algebra, please? How we know that F∖{x} is closure under operations in Ω?

Comment: @Miganyshi If it wasn't there would be terms $t_1,\dots,t_k$ and $k$-ary operation $f$ with $f(t_1,\dots,t_k)=x$. Now this would be an identity of the algebra, but the term algebra (aka absolutely free algebra) doesn't satisfy any identity.

Comment: Notice I edited the third line from below. I had overlooked something, but I think it's OK now.

Comment: "A≤F∖{xi}" means сardinality of sets?

Comment: @Miganyshi No, $A \leq B$, in this context, means $A$ is a sub-algebra of $B$.

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding, could you verify that I understood you clearly:
1) $\forall x \in X :$ F \ {x} is sub-algebry because F is free algebra. Next, F $\setminus ${x} is maximal proper subset of F, so it's a maximal sub-algebra.
2) Let A is a sub-algebra that A != F and $t(x_{1}, ... x_{n}) \in F \setminus A$; Then for some $1 \leq i \leq n : x_{i} \notin $ A is sub-algebra of $F \setminus \left \{ x_{i}  \right \}$. So A will be maximal sub-algebra $\Leftrightarrow $ for some i, term $t(x_{1}, ... x_{n}) = x_{i}$ And it means that F \ {x} is only maximal sub-algebra.

Comment: @Miganyshi It seems you understood it, although your way of exposing ideas is not very clear. Notice that sometimes the ability to expose ideas is a good step towards finding a proof for ourselves! Best wishes!